# How to mock local arraylist in method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Im trying to make an unit test for this method

```
 public void loadProductsFromAPI() {

        List<ProductEntity> databaseProducts = productService.getAllProductsFromBd();
        CountryTenant.country.forEach((key, value) -> {

            List<ProductEntity> productsByCountry = databaseProducts.stream()
                    .filter(product -> key.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(product.getCountry()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            List<ProductDTO> productsFromAPI = productsApi.getAllProductsFromAPI(value);
            List<ProductEntity> processedProducts = productService.persistProductsFromApi(key, productsByCountry, productsFromAPI);
        });

}
```

My problem its the `List<ProcuctEntity> productsByCountry`, that variable is created in the execution time. How can I mock that in my test case?

With mockito I already mock my products from db.

```
Mockito.when(productService.getAllProductsFromBd()).thenReturn(databaseProducts);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever find yourself trying to mock a *value*, you probably need to clean up your test plan. In this case, the `productsByCountry` is a *value* that is *calculated inside your method*: The correctness of that stream pipeline is part of what you need to verify. Mocking it would simply bypass ensuring that your logic is correct.

Instead, return appropriate test data from the mock `productService` and ensure that the correct filtered result if passed to `persistProducts`.

Comment: thanks i change my approach for the test, i move my stream into another method so i mock that fiddle instead

Comment: @Oku It's not even necessary to move the stream: The stream is just _part of how you implement this method_. You don't have to test each individual subcomponent of the method, only that it meets its requirements (whether it uses a stream, a for loop, etc.).